# MongoDB can't connect to Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

EDIT: I tried several different ports, killed tasks on ports and tried it again, it doesn't work.

today i started a tutorial on the MERN stack, but i can't connect to the server.
I get the following error when using npm run server:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVSWJ.png)

I installed the recommended version of node, used npm i to install express, mongoose, body-parser, concurrently and nodemon.
I followed every step of the tutorial but i can't get it to work.

These are my files:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true}) // Adding new mongo url parser
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mern_shopping_list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopping list built with the MERN stack",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Mario Hess",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

keys.js (yes, i edited MYNAME and PASSWORD!)

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI:'mongodb://<MYNAME>:<MYPASSWORD>@ds115193.mlab.com:15193/servasdu'
}
```

Comment: That error is telling you that the port 5000 is already in use. Try changing the port and seeing if it works, if it does check to see if there isn't any dangling processes of node or any other software running on that port.

Comment: I tried several different ports!

Comment: Hey mate i think u are getting problem with nodemon. Just try to run with node. Try npm start.

Comment: I tried to run with node, npm start. Same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
// const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
const db = 'mongodb://mario:M010101@ds115963.mlab.com:15963/stack2709';
// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  ) // Adding new mongo url parser
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

I've already made this database just for you. As you can see here, everything is just fine.

[image]

Hopefully my answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error said, another task is currently using the port 5000. Then, the solution is simple changing the port into something else. For example:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5050;
```

This is an alternative. If you're using Windows OS, try this:

In your Command Line:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :5000
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Then:

```
taskkill /pid xxxxx /f
```

The `xxxxx` need to be replaced with a `process IDs` on the right side. Most of time, the top first `pid`is the one we need.

By doing this, you will terminate the current task which is occupying the port 5000.

Comment: I just made another answer for you